# Why weren't there more assassination attempts?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In season 1, the small council of Westeros attempted to assassinate

> Daenerys,

but it backfired.

How come there weren't more assassination attempts?

1. Too busy with civil war?

They seemed to have time to write that

> Fake pardon for Jorah.

2. Funds?

They also seemed to have time the funds for a bounty on The Hound. Why not

> assassinating Daenerys

?

3. Not considering her a threat based on

> dead child

Or

> Daenerys being infertile?

Did they know about both of those?

Answer (score 8):

They've simply changed their minds about the situation.

Just before his death, Robert tells Ned he was right, and ask him to cancel the assassination.

> "The girl," the king said. "Daenerys. Let her live. If you can, if it... not too late... talk to them... Varys, Littlefinger...  don't let them kill her."
> (*A Game of Thrones*, Eddard XIII, Bantam Books Mass Market International Edition, page 505)

This may even have happened *before* the assassination attempt on Daenerys in Vaes Dothrak, but unfortunately they couldn't cancel it because the order had already been sent.

> "Robert had a change of heart concerning Daenerys Targaryen. Whatever arrangements you made, I want them unmade. At once.
>
> "Alas," said Varys. At once may be too late. I fear those birds have flown. But I shall do what I can, my lord."
> (*A Game of Thrones*, Eddard XIII, Bantam Books Mass Market International Edition, page 508)

Shortly after, the War of the Five Kings started, and Daenerys was more or less forgotten for a while. Moreover, after the death of Viserys, Drogo and Rhaego, Daenerys was left with barely a hundred Dothrakis (mostly old men, children and women) instead of 10 000 warriors, and they went in the desert east of the Dothraki Sea. The problem seemed to have sort itself. The Small Council only took interest in her again when they learned that she had conquered Slaver's Bay and that she had live dragons. At that point she was a potential danger again, so they sent a new pardon to Jorah to make Daenerys doubt his loyalty and send him away.

Additionally, Joffrey had no personal reason to hate the Targaryens like his <strike>father</strike> predecessor, which can explain the lack of interest for Daenerys.

Comment: So much text in spoilre tags and then you do the father/predecessor thing. Nice. :-)

Comment: Well the OP seems to have read the first book and/or seen the first season, so I don't think spoiler tags were needed. Any one who hasn't wouldn't understand the question in the first place, so i don't think they would read the answer...

Comment: Arnaud D., what do you mean by 'the problem seemed to have sort itself' ? Why make the fake pardon for Jorah then? It seems to me that she wasn't considered problematic from the time V, D and R died up until the point where they made the fake pardon for Jorah. So, like, why?

Comment: @BCLC I've expanded my answer a bit to address your question.